# UICollectionView Help What is the Best Way for adding section in MVVMCross Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

How to add Section headers in UICollectionView in Xamarin.iOS and MVVMCross.
I just want to ask the best approach. I am searching from 2 days but unable to find any simple approach. My data is List and and Section Contain List

My design looks like

[image]

Comment: Did you see http://slodge.blogspot.de/2013/05/n11-collectionview-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add supplementary views within a UICollectionView, you'll need to override the CollectionViewSource to provide them.

The base code for this in MvvmCross is in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxCollectionViewSource.cs and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxBaseCollectionViewSource.cs

A good Xamarin tutorial for CollectionViews is http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/

If you want to make the supplementary view bindable then you can do these by adapting the supplementary views in a similar way to the cells - e.g. copying and pasting the `BindingContext``DataContext` code from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxCollectionViewCell.cs and then ensuring you set the DataContext when the supplementary cell is used or reused within the collection view source.

There is an open issue requesting this functionality within MvvmCross or a sample -  https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/339 - but no-one (except me!) has ever commented on it... would be happy to see it added.

Comment: Thanks after the hard work of 2 days i achieved my goal. @Stuart If I'll help others in any way tell me. And 1 thing I think MVVMCross documentation is much old

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for the party, but here you have my working code for:

1. Using several sections in a collection
2. Use a header for each section

Change the data at your convenience:

```
public class SearchCollectionViewSource : MvxCollectionViewSource
{
    private List<SearchResult> results { get { return ItemsSource as List<SearchResult>; } }

    public SearchCollectionViewSource (UICollectionView collectionView) : base(collectionView) { }

    public SearchCollectionViewSource (UICollectionView collectionView, NSString defaultCellIdentifier) : base(collectionView, defaultCellIdentifier) { }

    public override UICollectionReusableView GetViewForSupplementaryElement (UICollectionView collectionView, NSString elementKind, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return (HeaderView)collectionView.DequeueReusableSupplementaryView(elementKind, HeaderView.Key, indexPath);
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections (UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return results.Count;
    }
    public override nint GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return results[(int)section].photos.Count;
    }

    protected override object GetItemAt(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return results [indexPath.Section].photos [indexPath.Row];
    }
}

public sealed class HeaderView : UICollectionReusableView
{
    public static string Key = "HeaderId";

    [Export("initWithFrame:")]
    public HeaderView(System.Drawing.RectangleF frame)
        : base(frame)
    {
        UIView separator = new UIView() { Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 10), BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray };
        AddSubview(separator);
    }
}
```